# How to use Maven profiles in Jmeter

Tags: java, maven, jmeter

I have different environments like prod,local,dev and QA to do performance testing. Based on the environment I want to change the threads,loopcount and domain name values. By using Jmeter properties I am able to change the values like below

***mvn process-resources jmeter:jmeter jmeter-analysis:analyze -Dthreads=30 -DloopCount=30 -DdomainName=mydomainname***

But I want to change this values by using **maven profiles**. could you please help me on it.I spent lot of time but I didn't get any clue how to use profiles in Jmeter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My expectation would be seeing your [pom.xml](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) file here so we could point you to the errors. It would also be an evidence of your attempts to resolve the issue instead of asking the community to do your work for you.

According to the [Introduction to Build Profiles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) documentation chapter it would be sufficient to add something like:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <threads>50</threads>
            <loopCount>50</loopCount>
            <domainName>devDomain</domainName>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>qa</id>
        <properties>
            <threads>1000</threads>
            <loopCount>1000</loopCount>
            <domainName>qaDomain</domainName>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

in order to define the properties for `dev` and `qa` environments correspondingly so when you run JMeter via Maven like:

```
mvn -P dev verify
```

you will get 50 users, 50 loops, etc.

and if you run `qa` profile like:

```
mvn -P qa verify
```

you will get 1000 users, 1000 loops, etc.

Full pom.xml just in case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmeter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <threads>100</threads>
        <loopCount>100</loopCount>
        <domainName>defaultDomain</domainName>
    </properties>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <threads>50</threads>
                <loopCount>50</loopCount>
                <domainName>devDomain</domainName>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>qa</id>
            <properties>
                <threads>1000</threads>
                <loopCount>1000</loopCount>
                <domainName>qaDomain</domainName>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Generate JMeter configuration -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>configuration</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>configure</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Run JMeter tests -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>

                    </execution>
                    <!-- Fail build on errors in test -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-check-results</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>results</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <propertiesUser>
                        <threads>${threads}</threads>
                        <loopCount>${loopCount}</loopCount>
                        <domainName>${domainName}</domainName>
                    </propertiesUser>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

More information: [How to Use the JMeter Maven Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin/)